# Capillary action on capillary joints

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capillary-action

There isn't much to say. In this question $B$ & $C$ are correct answers, and I can see how. However, I don't know how $D$'s validity could be determined. The solutions claimed that water will not enter $T_2$, but I don't understand why. That is my question.

PS: It isn't necessary to explain the answer mathematically! A rough explanation would do just fine!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I am not an expert in capillary forces. The following is just the result of me searching for the applicable laws. If there is a mistake in my line of argument, I will delete this answer.

Applying
$$h={{2 \gamma \cos{\theta}}\over{\rho g r}}$$
to a tube of pure type T1 yields
$$h={{2 \cdot 0.075 N/m \cdot \cos{0}}\over{1000 \frac{kg}{m^3}\cdot 10 \frac{N}{kg}\cdot 2\cdot 10^{-4}m}}=0.075m = 7.5 cm$$
So if the capillary joint is only 5 cm above the water surface, it is clear that the height of the water at least reaches the capillary joint.

But then the conditions of a tube of type T2 apply:
$$h={{2 \cdot 0.075 N/m \cdot \cos{60°}}\over{1000 \frac{kg}{m^3}\cdot 10 \frac{N}{kg}\cdot 2\cdot 10^{-4}m}}={{0.075 N/m \cdot 0.5}\over{1 \frac{N}{m^2}}}=0.0375m = 3.75 cm$$
So once the the fluid reaches the capillary joint at 5 cm height, the capillary forces inside T2 are not sufficient to lift it beyond that level.

The (dynamic) physical reality will probably look something like: the fluid level rises to the capillary joint at 5cm, but then the capillary forces suddenly decrease and so the fluid level tries to go below 5cm, where it starts lifting again. This oscillatory movement will eventually be damped (due to viscous forces), and the final level will settle to 5cm.

So the reference solutions seem to be right!